# Is it possible to import an existing contract without source code?

Tags: solidity, contract-deployment

There's no source code saved from the creator and not verified in scope (it's Klaytn). And I got the ownership of the contract.
I want to import the contract and interact with it to run some functions like setApprovalForAll.
Is it possible to import the contract without the source code? If so, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using interfaces. Just define it with the functions that exist on the target contract. E.g.:

```
interface IExample {
  function setApprovalForAll(address _operator, bool _approved) external;
}
```

By the `setApprovalForAll` example, I'm guessing it's an ERC721 contract you're interacting with. If so, you can just grab the interface from [EIP-721](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-721) directly

Once you have the interface, it's as simple as casting the address to it:

```
IExample example = IExample(contractAddress);
```

Then you can just call the functions on that instance